# Execute a shell script from HTML

Tags: html, bash, shell

I have written a simple HTML code that upon submit, it executes a bash script.
The script is in the correct folder, (cgi-bin).
When I load this page on firefox. It gives an error as

```
/somePATH/cgi-bin/script.sh could not be opened because an unknown error occurred.
```

Is the problem about script permissions? I have tried:

```
chmod 777
```

Here is a a part of the HTML code.

```
<form action="cgi-bin/script.sh" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Call my Shell Script">
</form>
```

EDIT:
The script basically just prints the date:

```
#!/bin/bash    
# get today's date
OUTPUT=$(date)
# script
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Demo</title></head><body>"
echo "Today is $OUTPUT <br>"
echo "You can do anything with this Schell Script"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Comment: What does the script look like?

Comment: @ShammelLee
edited in the question

Comment: What is the contents of the `cgi-gin/script.sh`? Also, please specify your server/config.

Comment: @ShammelLee
I added that script in the question. I am running it on my local host and HTTP service is running

Comment: Are you specifying a shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/env bash` or similar) at the top of the script?

Comment: Definitely need to know what HTTP server you're using and how it's configured.

Comment: @ShammelLee
I am using #!/bin/bash at the top

Comment: The issue is most-likely in your server config.

Comment: I have not configured any specific settings, I am just running an linux http server on this box. and I am running the page from the same host. 
Should I change/add something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a server side language. This is fairly easy with PHP

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   $output=shell_exec('sh /somePATH/cgi-bin/script.sh');
   echo $output;
 }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Call my Shell Script">
</form>
```

Include all your other HTML and save the file with an extension `.php`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of things you could check in your httpd.conf regarding CGI:

If you are loading or not the CGI module:

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
```

Verify your aliases for CGI

```
# ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
# ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
# documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
# run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
# client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
# directives as to Alias.
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/etc/your_httpd_path/cgi-bin/"
```

The rules of your directory of scripts:

```
# "/etc/your_httpd_path/cgi-bin/" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/etc/your_httpd_path/cgi-bin/">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Handlers for different file extensions (add .sh)

```
# AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
# actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
# or added with the Action directive (see below)
#
# To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
# (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
#
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .sh
```

Check if everything is configured as expected in your environment.

Btw as a good practice: Do not give 777 to the script, give specific permissions for the apache user, find out which user is running the httpd service (it's usually www-data) and do something like:

```
# remove extra file permissions for others
chmod o-wx /somePATH/cgi-bin/script.sh
# Define the user of the script (same as the user who runs httpd)
chown www-data  /somePATH/cgi-bin/script.sh
```