# Run a bash script from HTML (Javascript function)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic HTML file that takes inputs. I need to use those inputs to run a Bash file.

Right now I have:

```js
function generate(){
  var arg=document.getElementById("site").value;
  RUN THE FILE WITH ./filename arg
}
```

```html
Argument: <input type="text" id="arg" maxlength="3" size="3">
<br><input type="button" value="run file" onclick="generate()">
```

How can I run the bash file (./file arg)?

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44443164/9313033

Comment: check out [this link(http://bignosebird.com/prcgi.shtml) and related guidance on how to create and call a CGI.