# Running a bash script from html

Tags: php, html, linux, bash, shell

I am referring the post ,[Execute a shell script from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443164/execute-a-shell-script-from-html), ,

Here is mine file:
**example.php**

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
        shell_exec('bash script.sh');         
 }
?>   
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Call my Shell Script">
</form>
```

**script.sh**

```
filedex="classes.dex"
flag2="--output=$filedex"
filej="apple.java"

filecl="apple.class"

javac $filej
dx --dex "$flag2" "$filecl"
touch hello.txt
```

When I am running through the browser `localhost/example.php` , I could see my script is only generating `apple.class` file and `hello.txt` file i.e. it is only executing *javac $filej* and *touch hello.txt*. It is not executing `dx --dex "$flag2" "$filecl"` while when I am running through the shell i.e. `bash script.sh` it is genearting respective file. Why it is not generating through browser, I tried many times but failed. Please someone help me.

Comment: and what this has to do with `HTML`? `dx` might simply not be on `$PATH`.

Comment: Try using `passthru('bash script.sh 2>&a')`. This will show the output, including errors.

Comment: If `dx` isn't in one of the standard executable directories, use the full path to the program.

Comment: `$stdOut=shell_exec('echo $PATH');`  should also return the output. `getenv()` & `putenv()` can be used to extend the `$PATH` of user `apache`.

Comment: @Barmar, dx is in correct path and it is working when I am doing `bash script.sh`, It is not working when running from the browser.

Comment: The browser runs from a different user, it doesn't run your profile that sets `$PATH`.

Comment: @Barmar, Thanks a lot!! It works.  You were correct browser runs from a different user therefore complete path must be given. Thanks